# VirtualBox and non-system disk fragmented to 41%?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, defragment

I've installed VirtualBox reccently and have been playing around with installing different systems and working with them. I've created five different virutal machines:

1. Windows 10 Technical Preview
2. Windows Server 2012
3. Kali Linux 1.1
4. CentOs 7
5. Yosemite Zone

I created a virtual hard drive for each system using dynamically alocated memory (size depended ofc on a distro, so the Yosemite got 20GB, CentOS only 8GB and so on).

After couple of hours of playing with virtual machines slowed down. I got to an idea to defragment and optimize my drive using Windows Utility. **That showed 41% fragmented disk D!** The system disk is C. What is the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: Size of Drive D vs total working size of VM's might be relevant.

Comment: I've deleted the CentOS and Kali Linux machines. So I've got 32GB for Windows 10, 20GB for Yosemite Zone and 20GB for Windows Server 2012. This adds up to 72GB versus 120GB of drive D.

Comment: This is fragmentationt hat exists on the host OS on a secondary partition or on a secondary disk within the guest os?

Comment: On the host OS on a secondary partition.

Comment: Guys, what did I wrong that I have been minused. I want to excel at StackExchange but I need to know where I've done a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Windows NTFS formatted drives are fairly immune to fragmentation issues until they get to less than around 10% free.

Indeed, there are plenty of people who consider that NTFS actually runs faster with a level of fragmentation. However, if you see a sudden increase it will be because there isn't really enough space to handle the data updates without lots of shifting around.

Free up more space and defragment and the problem should go away.